# Parsing dates in JSON in d3/observablehq

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I've a JSON file with ISO8601 dates:

```
[
 {
  started_at: "2021-05-06T21:13:03.620Z",
  ...
 },
 ...
]
```

To work with these date vales they need to be parsed, but what's the easiest way of doing this?  Right now I've attached the JSON to the observable notebook and load it:

```
all_jobs = FileAttachment("pipeline.json").json()
```

And then iterate through the array to fix up the types:

```
{
for (let i = 0; i < all_jobs.length; i++) {
  if (all_jobs[i].started_at)
    all_jobs[i].started_at = new Date(all_jobs[i].started_at);

  if (all_jobs[i].finished_at)
    all_jobs[i].finished_at = new Date(all_jobs[i].finished_at);
}
return all_jobs;
}
```

But that is, obviously, horrible.  There must be a better solution, what is it?

Comment: It's not horrible. JSON is text so if you need the date as a JS type then using `new Date(...)` is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

You could traverse the object and replace the ISO timestamps with Date objects, something like:

```js
function isISODate(s) {
    return /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\:(\d{2})(\.\d{3})?(Z|([+-]\d{2})\:(\d{2}))/.test(s)
}

function replaceDates(obj) {
    for (const key in (obj)) {
        if (typeof obj[key] == "object") {
            replaceDates(obj[key]);
        } else {
            obj[key] = isISODate(obj[key]) ? new Date(obj[key]): obj[key];
        }
    }
}

let obj = [{ foo: { a: 42, bar: '2021-05-07T09:28:48Z' }}];

console.log("Original:", obj)
replaceDates(obj);
console.log("Modified:", obj)
console.log("Modified date:", obj[0].foo.bar.toString())
```